# Cannot copy feature class to database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, error-000210

I need to copy a feature class to a vector database but the message I got is that the feature class already exists.  However, I don't see it in the vector database - it is not there.  When investigating in SQL Management Studio, the table does exist.  So how do I fix up this can anyone please help?

> ERROR 000210: Cannot create output Database
>   Connections\Staging_forupdate@vector.sde\vector.GIS.Gov_Housing\Vector.GIS.Stock

Comment: Do you have permissions to see the problem feature class?

Comment: I think there is another feature in your database with the same name.

Comment: Hi,I have all read/write permissions.  The  Stock FC is not visible in the vector database in ArcCat but the table is present in the vector database in SSMS.   The whole process is  I need to rename Stock FC in ArcCat before i can copy the updated Stock FC to the vector db.  The rename tool does not see the Stock  FC whilst the copy features tool fail with the error message that the  Stock FC already exist.

Comment: How are you performing the copy?